# I can ping static IPs but cannot see them in browser

Tags: networking

I'm hopeless at networking so please forgive my ignorance. I have 4 machines master, slave02, slave03 and slave04 connected by a switch and have they have static IPs 192.168.1.1, 2, 3 and 4. They share an internet connection which works fine on all of them.

I can ping to them e.g. `ping slave4` and `ping 192.168.1.4` both work, but should I not also be able to browse to them e.g. `http://slave4` gives `unable to connect`?

I use Ub16.04 and they have files like:
/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
192.168.1.3    slave3
192.168.1.2    slave2
192.168.1.1    master
192.168.1.4    slave4
```

TIA!!

EDIT a rather odd example of the network config on one of the slaves:
[image] I can't edit the ifupdown but the Wired connection 1 looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What do you expect to see on the webpage if your idea worked?

Answer (score 6):

Seems you entered not enough of the information. 
Maybe I'm wrong and don't understood your issue, but if you want to browse another computer via http protocol, on that remote computer must be running some http-server and that host must be listening on the 80 (or differ, but by default - 80) port. Also that port have to be opened via firewall on http-host. To check, if that port is opened, you can try this command from the master computer:

```
nmap slave2 -p 80
```

or

```
nmap 192.168.1.2 -p 80
```

But anyway, first, webserver must be installed and configured on the slaves.